# Add value from radio button to existing link url use javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button

i have javascript script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
document.mainForm.onclick = function(){
var radVal = document.mainForm.pages.value;
result.innerHTML = 'You selected: '+radVal;
}
}//]]>  
</script>
```

radio button :

```
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm">
<input name="pages" type="radio" value="p1">
<input name="pages" type="radio" value="p2">
<input name="pages" type="radio" value="p3">
</form>
<span id="result"></span>


<a href="http://localhost/folder/blabla.php?p=book'>Book</a>
```

i want form click radio button the value from radio button has place on the link url, so that can be :

link : `<a href='http://localhost/folder/blabla.php?p=book&o=p1'>Book</a>`

add value **&o=p1**

can anyone help me?

thank you before

Answer (score 0):

Your form doesn't need a name, it's superfluous. The way you've attached the listener, *this* within the function will reference the form so you can do:

```
window.onload=function(){
  document.mainForm.onclick = function(event){
    var radVal = this.rads.value;
    // do stuff with radVal

}
```

For your solution, consider the following which adds the listener onload, then conditionally modifies the URL whenever there's a click inside the form. You could use a click event on each button, or look at the event and see if it came from one of the buttons, but I think it's simpler to just update the URL ever time there's a click:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var form = document.forms['mainForm'];

  if (form) {
    form.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var link = document.getElementById('a0');

      // Note that if there is only one such button, this will return a
      // reference to the single element so maybe querySelectorAll is better
      var buttons = this.pages;
      // var buttons = this.querySelectorAll('[name=pages]');

      for (var i=0, iLen=buttons.length; i<iLen; i++) {

        if (buttons[i].checked) {

          // Add to the href or replace if previously added
          link.href = link.href.replace(/\&.*|$/, '&o=' + buttons[i].value);

          // debug
          console.log(link.href);

          // Stop once checked button is found
          return;
        }
      }
    }, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, was building the URL incorrectly, try it now.